# Crawl embeded Flash video and render Javascript to obtain final GUI

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, flash

Now, I am encountering some difficulties when I have to scan or crawl a video URL link. This web page is using the Flash-based technology to embed the video and stream video.

In order to understand more clearly, this is a link example:

http://vnexpress.net/gl/the-gioi/tu-lieu/2012/11/bai-phat-bieu-thua-nhan-that-bai-cua-romney/

The above link has below content (HTML code for Flash embedded video):

```
        <div id="flashContent" style="text-align:center;width:100%;">                                                   
            <span id="FlashPlayer79237" class="Normal" align="center">B&#7841;n c&#7847;n c&#224;i <a href="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">Flash Player</a> &#273;&#7875; xem &#273;&#432;&#7907;c Clip n&#224;y.</span>              
        </div>
```

In this above article, there is a above video. However, when I tried to scan or crawl the content, the video could not run properly (because it could not load correct video link) and only show **Install Flash Player plugin** words (Certainly, the real web page needs to run some Javascript script or Flash script to obtain the real video link and stream this video for users)

Therefore, how can I render Flash and Javascript script through PHP or ASP.NET or Java? How can I get the correct video link when I crawl the web page? In this case, how can I obtain the **correct** Flash embedded video (HTML code)?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You should include some example of what you already tried, and where your current solution falls short.

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer, I want to make a note that if you need this information to do anything shady... please don't.

Disclaimer aside, for that particular site it is relatively easy.

The flashvars param (which is probably put there by Javascript) contains a value called xmlPath, which is a url encoded path (relative to their domain name). If you grab that and decode it, you get something like:

```
/Service/FlashVideo/PlayListVideoPage.asp?id=79237&f=108&t=1
```

which points to

```
 http://vnexpress.net/Service/FlashVideo/PlayListVideoPage.asp?id=79237&f=108&t=1
```

If you read that, it's an XML file which contains the URL of the actual video.

I'm not quite sure where that value is generated from. If you needed to do this fully server-side, you could use a headless browser to process it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if you download the content of web page, you can not see the below parameter:  <param name="flashvars" value="xmlPath=%2FService%2FFlashVideo%2FPlayListVideoPage.asp%3Fid%3D79237%26f%3D108%26t%3D1&amp;colorAux=0x0099ff&amp;colorBorder=0x333333&amp;colorMain=0xffffff&amp;local=embed&amp;mAuto=false&amp;repeat=false&amp;fvalue=108&amp;nid=1002300154">   Therefore, we can not track the video link through your way. The param value is generated via Javascript script and that is my question for this thread.